# How to secure the connection between dapr sidecar and application if the microservice is deployed in Azure container app

Tags: microservices, dapr, sidecar, azure-container-apps

I have deployed my microservices in Azure container app. I'm using dapr.
I would like to know how to secure the communication between the dapr sidecar and the application if the microservice is deployed in Azure Container App?
Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

PM for Container Apps here. Communication between your app and the dapr sidecar occurs over localhost because the two containers (your app, and the sidecar) are hosted together in an underlying Kubernetes pod. In terms of mTLS, if you make use of the service invocation API, you will get sidecar-to-sidecar encryption automatically. This communication between sidecars happens over gRPC. We manage the encryption as part of the platform, so no additional work is required on your side. Let me know if you have additional questions